# Displaying a undefined value in array.length

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json, object

I want to return the number of votes using `array.length` in ReactJS and display the number of votes

Expected output: `Votes: 2`

I have a object like this:

```
"likes" : {
    "like1" : {
      "blogId" : 1,
      "date" : "09-17-2021",
      "id" : "randomID_12345",
      "userId" : "evedave"
    },
    "like2" : {
      "blogId" : 1,
      "date" : "09-17-2021",
      "id" : "randomID_123123",
      "userId" : "evedarryle"
    }
},
```

**NOTE: This is returning as a object but I declare my state as a array**
**Reference** :
[image: Screenshot of the object]

Here's my code:

```
const blogItems = useSelector((state) => state.blogs);

const [blogData, setBlogData] = useState([]);
const [blogVotes, setBlogVotes] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    setBlogData(blogItems);

    const finalVotesData = blogData.items?.find((blog) => {
      return blog.id === 1;
});

setBlogVotes(finalVotesData?.likes);
}, [blogItems, blogData.items, blogVotes]);
console.log(blogVotes);
```

Here's the `array.length`

```
<p>{blogVotes.length}</p>
```

How can I display the number of votes using `array.length`?

Comment: Why aren't the likes actually stored in an array?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @jarmod Automatically stored as object. I already uploaded the screenshot for the reference.

Comment: @TheFool Ho can I display the number of votes using array.length?

Comment: I don't know about your object problem, but you can always use `Object.keys(obj).length`.

Comment: It's not an array (but probably should be) so you can't use array.length (obviously). Consider changing the producer of this data to generate an array or otherwise add your own custom length function.

Comment: You can declare it as anything you want, but if that's the structure of the data, the likes are being stored as properties, not as elements of the array. You would have to create a `length` property with a getter that gets the number of properties of the `like` property value.

Answer (score 0):

Following `redux` tutorial, seems you can create a new selector to modify `blogs`. *Sorry i don't know if your blogs is  same as likes, I'm a bit confused on that.*

```
const blogItemsSelector = createSelector(
  (state) => state.blogs,
  (blogs) => Object.keys(blogs).map(key => ({ key, ...blogs[key] }))
)
```

After this you can use the new creator,

```
const blogItems = useSelector(blogItemsSelector)
```

Here's the tutorial, you might find more stuff useful there, https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks. Anyway this is an idea. Of course you can go straight to parse data instead of a new selector.